# How to update data in Database when status_choice removed from models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

In models I had status choices for

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="FIELD_1", choices=STATUS)
```

like this:

```
STATUS = (
        ('FIELD_1', _('value FIELD_1')),
        ('FIELD_2', _('value FIELD_2')),
        ('FIELD_3', _('value FIELD_3')),
        ('FIELD_4', _('value FIELD_4')),
        ('FIELD_5', _('value FIELD_5')),
    )
```

I have removed `('FIELD_5', _('value FIELD_5')),` and `('FIELD_4', _('value FIELD_4')),` from `STATUS`  choices. How can I update `status` value in Database to `FIELD_1` when it was `FIELD_5` or `FIELD_4`

Comment: just makemigration and migrate after

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour I did but FIELD_5 and FIELD_4 still in DB

Comment: Create a migration which only adds the new choice or remove. Write a method to take all models with the old choice, and delete them or update then migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) operation to the migration that changes the choices, update the values for the old rows there

```
from django.db import migrations, models


def update_status(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'MyModel')
    MyModel.objects.filter(status__in=['FIELD_4', 'FIELD_5']).update(status='FIELD_1')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', 'xxx_previous'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_status),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='status',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('FIELD_1', 'value FIELD_1'), ('FIELD_2', 'value FIELD_2'), ('FIELD_3', 'value FIELD_3')], default='FIELD_1', max_length=50),
        ),
    ]
```